# SwiftUI TabView crashes when displaying tab containing data that changed when said tab was invisible

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabview

A SwiftUI TabView contains to two tabs. Each displays data from the same model. If the data is missing, a ProgressView is displayed, if the data is present, the current value is displayed.
In the example model the data is set asynchronously after 2 seconds to cause the problem. (In my real app, the data is set as a result of an async call.)

After running the app, the first tab is displayed containing the ProgressView and the data is displayed after 2 seconds. So far everything seems to work.
When switching from the first Tab to the second the app crashes somewhere 75 levels deep in SwiftUI display code:

> (AG::Graph::add_indirect_attribute:) with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

What am I doing wrong and how can I circumvent the problem, if it is an SwiftUI Bug?

The following code causes the crash:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Model: ObservableObject{
    @Published var value:Double?
    
    init(){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3){
            self.value = 2.0
            print("value set")
        }
    }
}

@main
struct TabViewUpdatingTestApp: App {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(model: model)
        }
    }
}

struct Tab: View {
    let name:String
    @ObservedObject var model:Model
    
    var body: some View {
        if let mvalue = model.value{
            Text("name: \(name), value: \(mvalue)")
        }else{
            ProgressView().font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model:Model
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Tab(name: "Tab 1", model: model)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab 1", systemImage: "1.circle")
                }
            Tab(name: "Tab 2", model: model)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab 2", systemImage: "2.circle")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me. A possible workaround may be to force-refresh the `TabView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Tab(name: "Tab 1", model: model)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab 1", systemImage: "1.circle")
                }
            Tab(name: "Tab 2", model: model)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab 2", systemImage: "2.circle")
                }
        }
        .id(model.value) // add here
    }
}
```

Alternatively, instead of redrawing the view when `model.value` changes, you can create some other variable that changes only once (so you don't refresh the `TabView` every time but only once at the beginning).

Comment: Thanks! This prevents the crash from occurring in my real code and since this value is only set once there is no danger of too many redraws.
Additionally I didn't know about the id modifier. Could be usefull in the future to do some forced redraws.

Comment: Thanks! Took me a while before finding this post. My crash message was "Attempted to scroll the collection view to an out-of-bounds item (1) when there are only 1 items in section 0". Adding it here, so search engines can point to this awesome answer!